# Multiple computer on one ip in socket programming

Tags: sockets, ip, chat

I'm trying to communicate over internet with sockets. I don't know how to connect to a computer which is on internet and has dynamic ip. Is it possible to communicate over global ip's with sockets?

Sometimes  there are multiple computers on one global ip. I don't know how to handle this situation neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides not being sure about the dynamic address, connecting to a dynamic IP is pretty much the same as with a static IP. To be able to resolve the dynamic IP address, you can:

- if it is your machine, you can subscribe to a service such as [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.org) or [PeanutHull](http://www.oray.net), which gives you a subdomain .dyndns.org and handles the dynamic
  address change for you
- if you control the code on the dynamic IP, you can have it connect to your fixed IP host first

For the case of several computers sharing a single IP behind a rounter these will also help, and you can still have the router forward a port of the global IP to the a port of the computer behind it. In this case, if the local IP behind the router changes, the router will handle it for you.

And as [Seán Labastille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1972476/sean-labastille) says on the comments, there's also NAT traversal.

Comment: I believe NAT traversal might be an option if you do not have code behind the single IP address depending on your precise scenario.

Comment: My server has already static Ip. I don't have problem about connecting to server. I have problem when server tries to connect to clients. For example a client which has a global ip as "42.196.212.8" sent a request to server. And server wants to send some data to that ip. But in that ip there are several computers. How to deliver the response to correct computer?